# What does "delete" actually do in c++?

Tags: c++

I am not sure what exactly the command `delete` does in c++? As far as I know, to free memory I have to use `delete` on objects, that I previously instantiated with `new`, like:

```
Obj* object = new Obj();
delete object;
```

But does `delete` actually deletes data from my objects, does it in any way alter the object and data inside the object itself OR does it just call the corresponding destructor? If the destructor is empty, does useing `delete` have any consequences to the object? The reason for this question is as follows:

If I just delete objects this way, the pointer gets invalid, and my program does crash. So, I think I should just call the destructor with the delete command and take further steps inside the destructor function do actually do the cleanup and to be sure that other objects refering to this object know that the pointer is truly invalid.

Comment: "If I just delete objects this way, the pointer gets invalid, and my program does crash". That means there's a bug somewhere in your program. The two lines of the shown code are perfectly valid C++, by themselves. If the above crashes, this indicates that there's a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: "*and to be sure that other objects referring to this object know that the pointer is truly invalid*": If that is necessary you have a design problem in your lifetime management. It should not happen that an object is still holding a pointer or reference to the object when it is being destroyed.

Comment: `delete object` calls the destructor of `Obj` and passes the value of the pointer `object` to one of the overloads of a function named `operator delete()` which (by default) causes the memory occupied by `*object` to no longer exist as far as your program is concerned. The value of `object` does not change, but any usage of the object (e.g. accessing any non-static member of `*object`) or accessing the memory it occupied causes undefined behaviour. If you want the value of `object` to change, you need to assign it (e.g. `object = nullptr` after `delete object`).

Comment: "other objects refering to this object"  - you should generally avoid this situation, or manage it via smart pointers . Doing lifetime management in an ad-hoc manner is asking for endless debugging trouble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides calling the destructor, the `delete` operator deallocates the memory that was previously allocated by `new`.  This memory goes back to the available pool of memory that can be allocated.

This also means that `object` now points to invalid memory and any attempt to use it, or any other pointer that pointed to it, will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is probably what is happening in your program.

So your progam most likely has an issue with who "owns" the pointer.  You shouldn't be calling `delete` on a pointer value that is still being used elsewhere in your program.

Comment: From my understanding of [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete), the delete-expression invokes `operator delete` after the dtor. While it almost certainly will deallocate memory as you wrote in practice, is it required to do so in order to conform to language requirements, or can it perform something else such as a no-op?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ--     It is not required to do anything.   The program has undefined behaviour if it accesses memory that has been passed to `operator delete()`.    All that will happen if `operator delete()` is a no-op is that the memory will be leaked, but your program should not reuse any pointers that have been passed to operator delete to avoid undefined behaviour  (undefined behaviour means the STANDARD does not guarantee any particular outcome - an implementation can do what it likes, including allowing your code to access a deleted object as if it actually exists OR simply crashing)